# El Plan ordenador

Tags: significado

¿Qué significa "ordenador" en "[En 1750 Santiago Bonavía trazó el Plan ordenador de una nueva ciudad](https://rutas.aranjuez.es/routes/ciudad-cortesana)"? No creo que signifique computadora electrónica. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Se refiere a algo que *ordena*, *acomoda*, *organiza*, etc. Creo que buscando las acepciones de la palabra en cualquier diccionario se puede entender. Para la próxima un poco más de esfuerzo e investigación, por favor

Comment: Encontré la acepción de "1. adj. Que ordena. U. t. c. s." en RAE, antes de hacer la pregunta, pero no podía "conectar los puntos". Pensaba yo: ¿ordenar qué? ¿el plan? ¿pero en qué sentido'? De todas formas, .

Comment: El plan ordenador *para* hacer una nueva ciudad. Somos un poco imprecisos con las preposiciones, suele pasar. Vas a tener que acostumbrarte

Comment: Se nota que así es ... gracias

Comment: El nombre completo es [Plan General de Ordenación Urbana](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_General_de_Ordenaci%C3%B3n_Urbana), que luego se puede encontrar simplificado de muchas maneras.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por la información, aerobiomat!